# Extract certain cell from Excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Help a poor scientist out with Excel. I did an experiment where the computer writes out an excel sheet for each measurement. So my 'workbook' file contains dozens of 'sheets' with tables on each one. I need to plot a timecourse where I track the value of a particular cell across all the sheets. I.e. what I want to do is copy say, cell A3, from each sheet in the workbook to somewhere else in the workbook such that I can then easily create a chart.

Does anyone know a command to extract the value of a certain cell from each sheet in a workbook? Or a simple macro I could write?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer by looking at [tech recipes](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1604/excel_how_to_reference_cells_in_other_worksheets/).

Excel provides a syntax whereby you can specific the name of the sheet and the cell name afterwards.

```
=Sheet1!A1 + Sheet2!A1 + Sheet3!A1
```

Note, if you have spaces in your sheet name it needs to include quotes around the name.

```
='Sheet1 with space'!A1 + Sheet2!A1 + Sheet3!A1
```